# How do I stop a partial View from displaying footer information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a partial view that I am calling by my Index and the Partial view does not have the header inside it, but it still has the footer.  I am wondering why this is and how can I remove the footer?
[image]

```
PARTIAL VIEW!!!!!!
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<SQDCDashboard.Core.ViewModels.SafetyChartViewModel>()
                .Name("safetyIncident-chart")
                .Title("Safety Incidents For ")
                .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top))
                .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults => seriesDefaults.Column().Stack(true))
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetSafetyIncidentChart", "Display").Data("DropDownValue")))
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Column(model => model.NumSafeDays).Name("Safe Days").Color("green").CategoryField("Month");
                    series.Column(model => model.NumIncDays).Name("Incident Days").Color("red").CategoryField("Month");
                })
                .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false)))
                .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}")).Min(0).Max(32))
                .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0}"))
)
```

Comment: What is the cshtml for your partial view? Looks like the partial is also loading the shared footer view.

Comment: we need to see your code (_layout, the parent view, the partial view and any other views being rendered here) to be able to answer the question... somewhere you have that footer twice between your shared views, view, and partial views... you could simply search the solution for the footer text and probably get a pretty quick answer

Comment: A "partial view" is a View unless you specifically get it using `return PartialView()` or `Html.Partial`

Comment: Thanks Camilo, I guess I am wondering why did it not show the <head> when I called the partial view but did show the footer.

Comment: I cannot tell you without looking at the entire code, which is probably way too much for a question

Answer (score 2):

```
return PartialView("YourViewName");
```

or, If you are returning plain view:
At top of your cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

In controller method:

```
return View("YourViewName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the view using your partial view. It seems you have code there after including your partial view.